# serious stuck on: validations not triggered for nested resource with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, nested-attributes

**Im seriously stuck on an issue where I have a User and Profile model. 
whatever I try it seems validations are not triggered for any of the Profile attributes**

- The profile model belongs to User. User has_one Profile
- On registration form using fields_for to have some profile fields displayed ( gender, and city and country )
- Whatever I tried, I'm unable to let validation work for *gender and city* ( the fields_for profile fields)

**My form:**

```
- title t(:title, :scope => :register)
%h1= yield(:title)

  = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } , :validate => true , :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|

    = f.input :username,                  :label  => t(:username)
    = f.input :email,                     :label  => t(:email),
                                          :hint   => t(:hint_email_visible)
    = f.input :password,                  :label  => t(:password), :require => true
    = f.input :password_confirmation,     :label  => t(:password_confirm)


    - resource.build_profile
    = f.fields_for :profile do |f|

      #div

        = f.hidden_field :form, :value => "signup"

        .clear

        = f.input :gender,                :collection => [['Male', 'male'], ['Female', 'female']],
                                          :as => :radio

    = f.input :city,
              :readonly => "readonly",
              :label => t(:city)

    .ruler

    = f.input :country,
              :label => "Your country",
              :collection => [DataCountry.where(:code => 155).first],
              :value => @city,
              :id => "country",
              :name => "country"

    .clear


    = f.button :submit, t(:submit, :scope => :register) + " »"
```

**My User model has this:**

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

**My Profile model with validations is like:**

```
  validates_presence_of :gender
  validates_presence_of :city
  validates_presence_of :country
```

**My PARAMS:**

```
-- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: <mytokenhere>
user: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  invite_code: ''
  username: username
  email: ''
  password: ''
  password_confirmation: ''
  profile_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    form: signup
    gender: male
    dob(3i): '9'
    dob(2i): '7'
    dob(1i): '1942'
    city: 'somevalue'
    country: 'somevalue'
commit: Register »
action: create
controller: registrations
```

Rails console does:

```
User.new


 => #<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, password_salt: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, authentication_token: nil, username: nil, is_blocked: nil, is_deleted: nil, role: nil, slug: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, last_seen: nil, credits: nil, invite_code: nil, is_moderated: nil, locale: nil, status: nil, login_token: nil>
```

Profile.new

```
 => #<Profile id: nil, user_id: nil, gender: nil, country: nil, state: nil, city: nil, status: nil, counter_cache: nil>
```

--
**UPDATE 19 Jul '12**

I added the

```
    - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
  = message
  .clear
```

To the form to see what exactly is happening and this throws the following list of errors:

```
Email can't be blank
Email can't be blank
Password can't be blank
Password can't be blank
Profile city can't be blank
Profile gender can't be blank
Profile is invalid
Username can't be blank
Password confirmation can't be blank
```

So it seems the validation is checked.... 
But no error styling is applied! Also the profile is invalid???? Im not sure but does that refer to the

Comment: Try changing to `validates_inclusion_of :gender, in: %w(male female)` and see if it gives you an error message

Comment: Thx tried that to no avail sadly. I try it with some other profile fields I will add to the form perhaps its a gender related issue

Comment: Have you tried putting `validates_associated :profile` in your `User` model?

Comment: @HargrimmTheBleak yes just tried same results, restarted app but won't work neither. I have in addition put a location in beside gender in the profile table with validations set

Comment: OK maybe you can paste your controller actions here? What do you get in `params` when POSTing the form?

Comment: @HargrimmTheBleak thx I have added the form params to the post as you see they are under profile_attributes.

Comment: Still curious about the `create` action in your `RegistrationsController`. Also on a side note, if you're using `attr_accessible` in your `User` model, check if you have `:profile_attributes` listed there.

Comment: Added the registrations#create (Default devise one with some small extra's added before the super ) and yes I have also :profile_attributes in my users model

Comment: OK seems I'm running out of ideas too. Does the profile association actually get saved? In your example params I can see a gender value being passed, is it valid? If it doesn't get saved, I'd try to explicitly do that in your create action after the call to `super` and see if that would raise a validation error.

Comment: Thx @HargrimmTheBleak I try that and post back here. IF I select male of female radio button then the value is saved in profiles table yes. Just no validation on it :( any other suggestions maybe on how to get this working? Is there an working example somewhere with validations to check the code? this can't be impossible can it? you must be able to validate attributes from associated models?

Comment: Can you please post your whole `User` and `Profile` model as well as the `RegistrationsController#create` action so that I can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many hours spend trying to fix this now the solution is *very* simple based on suggestions in this topic I found out that instead of

**WRONG:**

```
- resource.build_profile
```

**CORRECT:**

```
- resource.build_profile unless resource.profile
```

what this does is not clean the profile but uses the old one if its available... so not cleaning out all the errors! hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 3):

First off, the params that you pasted include values for the profile's city, country and gender. If this is accurate, then validation *should* pass, because the `Profile` model validates the presence of these 3 fields -- and they are present.

I also note that you're doing `resource.build_profile` in the view, which should build up a default profile belonging to the user. If any values are being assigned in the profile during instantiation, this would cause them to make their way into the form, and ultimately into the params hash.

So my guess is that you're populating the fields somewhere along the line, perhaps in the `User` or `Profile` models. You should check those again, particularly during initialization of a new profile.

That's all I can guess at from the data you've given. If you still can't find the issue, you could try committing it (or a separate app which reproduces the issue, if you're uncomfortable sharing your real app) to GitHub so that we can analyze the issue more directly.

EDIT: just noticed, in your bounty you wrote:

> anyone can provide a working example [of] nested resources and validations

So, see https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/rubytastic for a simple example of user validation with nested attributes for a Profile, modeled after your question. It validates `User#email`, `Profile#city`, `Profile#country` and `Profile#gender`.

Comment: If I leave the 3 fields empty, the form still validates, there are no errors ( I set the 3 profile fields to be required ). Thx a lot for the comment and taking some time to write an example. I check them out tomorrow in full detail and report back then. thx again.

Comment: I used the loop all errors code from your example , didn't think a second about trying that it seems that error styling is not applied. So the fields are invalid but there is no CSS also the forms are not repopulated. Im going to strip my profile model now to see if any code is causing these issues.

Comment: Yes, Rails 2 had a `<%= f.error_messages %>` method but it was removed in Rails 3 because the core team felt it was too "magic", in that no one ever really understood what it did. So now you have to do styling yourself, but it's not much more work anyway. The forms might not be repopulated because of your `resource.build_profile`, which might be overwriting the previous (invalid) profile with a brand-new (blank) one.

Comment: is there a way around this? is there a way to initialize the profile other way? Rather not get a very messy form with all kinds of customs validations just because i have nested resource, why doesn't simple_form pick it up, can we consider this a BUG? Using rails 3 though and you error loop code works fine

Comment: Well, initializing the profile in the view is part of the problem in this case. You should initialize the profile in the controller's `#new` method. You don't need to initialize it in the `create` method because it is already initialized from the nested attributes. I'm not familiar with simple_form so I don't know if it is working properly. You may need to contact the simple_form author and file a report in their issue tracker.

Comment: Based on your comment @sinisterchipmunk i have don't this and it works:     - resource.build_profile unless resource.profile
 the profile was recreated every time this finally solved my issue!! thx all

Comment: Glad to have helped. Do you need any more assistance with this question?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have any default value in the database set.It seems that in the form params, you have pasted in the question, gender has value `male` passed. Is this form params passed even when you didnt check anything for gender? In that case, this must be a case where the gender field in the database must have the default value for gender as `male`. In that case, even a new `Profile` model object will have its gender attribute as `male`, and so it will pass the validations and save the gender as `male` in the database. For example, I have a boolean field `is_admin` in the users table and set its default value as `false` or `0`. Then if I do this:

```
User.new
=>  #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, is_admin: false>
```

You can see the `is_admin` attribute is set to `false` instead of `nil`. Now if we do not pass any value for `is_admin`, here it will be saved as `false` in the database and also will not trigger the validation for `is_admin` field, as it is present in the object's attributes (with value `false`).

Comment: I checked for this but this is not the case, gender is not set

Comment: @Rubytastic: You have given the `User.new` object. `gender` is in the profiles table, right? Can you check the output of `Profile.new`?

Comment: Ive updated the output of profile.new. Look tonight in detail to all the answers and solution provided in this topic, thx for the support.